# I am having problems with table placement

Tags: tables, formatting

Hi I am sorry if this is a repeat, I tried to find a similar problem but I could not. I am making Cayley tables and I quite like the ease of the code I am using, but something strange keeps happening. I put the code in for the table, then write some words and then put the code for another table, but when I compile, both tables are above the words that were supposed to be in the middle.

example:

`\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|}
    + & e & a & b\\
    \hline
    e & e & a & b\\
    \hline
    a & a & ? & ? \\
    \hline
    b & b & ? & ? \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}`

words words words

`\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|}
    + & e & a & b\\
    \hline
    e & e & a & b\\
    \hline
    a & a & ? & ? \\
    \hline
    b & b & ? & ? \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}`

But when I compile the tables are on top and the "words words words" is under both tables.

Any help would be appreciated. This is my first post so I hope I did everything correctly.

Comment: Use  with `\begin{table}[htb]` for both tables.

Comment: **Welcome** to **TeX.SX!**

Comment: Is there a way for me to mark that it has been answered?